# How to make times ending `:00` accessible (e.g. 14:00)

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

Voice over reads the following `NSStrings` like so

---

#### `14:15`

> "Fourteen fifteen."

This is clearly a time

---

#### `14:00`

> "Fourteen."

This is ambiguous.

---

If the time `14:00` appears in the status bar it correctly reads it as

> "Fourteen hundred hours"

How do I achieve this in a localised way?

[image: iOS reading out correct time]

Comment: Have you tried to give UILabel a custom attribute by overriding the `accessibilityLabel` property. Use the appropriate NSDateFormatter with `timeStyle` set to `.MediumStyle` and it should speak out as time.

Comment: @dirkgroten - Thanks for the suggestion.  Medium style will still produce the text "14:00" right? if so then it will have the same result since the `accessiblityValue` only sees the raw NSString output.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I achieve this in a localised way?

Overriding the `accessibilityLabel` with the result of [`NSDateFormatter::localizedStringFromDate()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDateFormatter/localizedStringFromDate:dateStyle:timeStyle:) will be the best thing to do because you can only rely upon iOS's own algorithm to handle any language.

The problem of doing it in a *localised way* is that it will depend on the language you want.

In French, for instance, you will never pronounce the `:00`, "14:00" will be read as *quatorze heures* (*"fourteen hours"*). "14:12" is "quatorze heures douze" (fourteen hours twelve, not "fourteen twelve")

In Spanish, even if reading 24 hours format, you will always read it on a 12 hours basis: "14:00" will be read as *las dos de la tarde* (*"two in the afternoon"*) not talking about the distinction between *"de la tarde"* and *"de la noche"*.

In both French or Spanish, you will never say *hundred*.

Comment: Good points.  There are locale sensitive ways of reading times.  This is why it would be hard to write something that converts the string into words i.e. "14:00" -> "Fourteen hundred hours".  However,  I don't think anything you have suggested will help.  The method takes a style (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDateFormatterStyle) and will output a string either `14:00` or `2:00 PM`.  Voice over only sees the output string, so will still read it "Fourteen" I think.  I will give it a go tho.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it's very easy ;-)

14:00 = Fourteen **o'clock**

Comment: I think it's a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work in a localized way as expected by Robert.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Date {
    
    func accessibilityTime() -> String? {
        let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute], from: self)
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.unitsStyle = .spellOut
        return formatter.string(for: dateComponents)
    }
}
```

this uses the spell-out unit using the DateComponentsFormatter to announce your time in a localised way. It does not fully implement as anyone on the street would say ("a quarter to three" will be announced as "fourteen o'clock and forty-five minutes"*) but it beats the "fourteen forty-five" announcement.

I hope this helps a lot of apps become more accessible for more people. :)

- I have tried this using my native Dutch Language. For Dutch native speakers ("kwart voor drie" becomes "viertien uur en vijfenveertig minuten")